# Multiparameter string value on a Report from Reporting Services in Sharepoint (Managed Subscriptions)

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, multiparameter

I have a huge problem trying to configure a managed subscription (Data-Driven). I cant find out how to put multivalue from a Personalized List on Sharepoint.

In my report query i have the following condition:

```
and invent_dim.inventsiteid in (@p_Site)
```

where `@p_site` is a list of "sitios" from where it has to search records.

On the normal report visualization it has a combobox to select as many sitios as the user wants

[image: Sitios Multi-Select]

But on a managed susbcription i've tried with `''`, `,`, `""`, `multilines`, `multilines with ,`, etc...

I can't find any related info on the web and i was hoping that you could help me. The only thing i figured i can do is to repeat the recipients but thats a lot of work for the user. And i can't define it on the subscription configuration because the sites varies from recipients to recipients.

Thanks in advance for your help! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by defining the following in the parameter default values expression:
`=join(yourParameter.Value,",")`

Comment: Hi Gil. Thank you very much for answering. I tried with =join(parameters!p_Site.Value,",") on the visal studio 2008 but when i try to run it (so later i can try it on Sharepoint) i get the error "an error occurred during local report processing p_site". Where do i put that instruction? on the personalized list in sharepoint? Thanks!